# How to replace values under severals conditions using purrr?

Tags: r, apply, tidyverse, purrr, data-wrangling

The post has been edit at Aug 17, 2020 to make the example looks more like my actual data.

The days always come first either with 1 or 2 digits. The months always come second either in full or in part and in French. The years always come third either with 2 or 4 digits.

---

I'm learning to code with tidyverse packages. I'm trying to replace every elements in a variable by an other string if they match specific conditions. The problem is that I can only do it one condition at the time. I would like to know how to achieve it at severals condition a the time.

Here's a reproductible exemple :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
        
tib <- tibble(
  ID = 1:6, 
  Date = c("1-JAN-20", "15-JUILL-20", "30 DEC 2020", 
           "1-JAN-20", "15-JUILL-20", "30 DEC 2020"), 
  Comm = c("Should be 2020-01-01", "Should be 2020-06-15", "Should be 2020-12-30", 
           "Should be 2020-01-01", "Should be 2020-06-15", "Should be 2020-12-30"))
head(tib)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Date        Comm                
  <int> <chr>       <chr>               
1     1 1-JAN-20    Should be 2020-01-01
2     2 15-JUILL-20 Should be 2020-06-15
3     3 30 DEC 2020 Should be 2020-12-30
4     4 1-JAN-20    Should be 2020-01-01
5     5 15-JUILL-20 Should be 2020-06-15
6     6 30 DEC 2020 Should be 2020-12-30

# Returns the unique values of the character variables execept the "Comm" one. So, it
# returns only one in that case, but my original data have severals ones.
            
tib %>% select(where(is.character), -Comm) %>% map(~ unique(.x))
    
$Date
[1] "1-JAN-20"   "15-JUILL-20" "30 DEC 2020"
```

Here we are! The following code works, but I wonder if there's a better way to atcheive it instead of copy/pass the same code line every time and changing it.

```
tib <- tib %>% mutate(Date = case_when(Date == "1-JAN-20" ~ "2020-01-01", 
                                       Date == "15-JUILL-20" ~ "2020-06-15",
                                       Date == "30 DEC 2020" ~ "2020-12-01"))
head(tib)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Date       Comm                
  <int> <chr>      <chr>               
1     1 2020-01-01 Should be 2020-01-01
2     2 2020-06-15 Should be 2020-06-15
3     3 2020-12-01 Should be 2020-12-30
4     4 2020-01-01 Should be 2020-01-01
5     5 2020-06-15 Should be 2020-06-15
6     6 2020-12-01 Should be 2020-12-30
```

Since I will have to do this manipulation on other variables, how could I build a function that would accomplish this?

Also, I would like to know if you know some good documentations/tutorials to learn Purrr package?

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: one of the most important things is not to insert `rm(list=ls())` when you post your code here, because the user who is reproducing your code can unintentionally have his variables removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While handling dates/times you should use standard date time functions for manipulation. Don't replace dates one by one using `str_replace`. Imagine you have 1000's of dates with different years, it is not practically possible to list each one of them. In this case, you can use `lubridate::dmy` to convert them to date object, for more complicated cases there is `lubridate::parse_date_time` which can convert variables in different format to dates.

```
tib %>% dplyr::mutate(new_date = lubridate::dmy(Date))

#     ID Date        Comm                 new_date  
#  <int> <chr>       <chr>                <date>    
#1     1 01-JAN-20   Should be 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
#2     2 15-JUN-20   Should be 2020-06-15 2020-06-15
#3     3 30 DEC 2020 Should be 2020-12-30 2020-12-30
#4     4 01-JAN-20   Should be 2020-01-01 2020-01-01
#5     5 15-JUN-20   Should be 2020-06-15 2020-06-15
#6     6 30 DEC 2020 Should be 2020-12-30 2020-12-30
```

If you want dates in specific format, you can use the `format` function on `new_date`.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this when your date format is not constant and standard. I edited the post to adapt the exemple and make it looks more like my actual data.

Comment: It is weird, how can Lubridate know 01-JAN-20 is 2020-01-01 and not 1920-01-01?

Comment: @MathieuBernier You need to have dates in one language, either English or French. Also your R locale should be in the same language while using the above code. There is `month.abb` constant which gives you month name in current locale.

Comment: @daniellga This is standard R format not specific to `lubridate`. From `?strptime` - `%y - On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 `

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try dplyr::case_when:

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

# A tibble that looks like my data.
tib <- tibble(
  ID = 1:6, 
  Date = c("01-JAN-20", "15-JUN-20", "30 DEC 2020", 
           "01-JAN-20", "15-JUN-20", "30 DEC 2020"), 
  Comm = c("Should be 2020-01-01", "Should be 2020-06-15", "Should be 2020-12-30", 
           "Should be 2020-01-01", "Should be 2020-06-15", "Should be 2020-12-30"))
head(tib)

tib %>% select(where(is.character), -Comm) %>% map(~ unique(.x))

tib <- tib %>% mutate(Date = dplyr::case_when(Date == "01-JAN-20" ~ "2020-01-01",
                                              Date == "15-JUN-20" ~ "2020-06-15",
                                              Date == "30 DEC 2020" ~ "2020-12-01"))

> tib
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     ID Date       Comm                
  <int> <chr>      <chr>               
1     1 2020-01-01 Should be 2020-01-01
2     2 2020-06-15 Should be 2020-06-15
3     3 2020-12-01 Should be 2020-12-30
4     4 2020-01-01 Should be 2020-01-01
5     5 2020-06-15 Should be 2020-06-15
6     6 2020-12-01 Should be 2020-12-30
```

The best thing to try to do here is to transform your Date column into Date class using the "anytime" package. Although you would have to manually fix your Date column so all years have 4 digits. If years are always in the last place of the date, that can be an easy thing to do.

Comment: I edited the post to make it looks more like my actual data. The days always come first either with 1 or 2 digits. The months always come in the middle but are written either in full or in part in french. The years are always at the end but some times with 2 digits and some times with 4 digits. Will I need to change them manually?

Comment: @MathieuBernier you can try stri_replace_all or even case_when to try to homogenize the months based on patterns, but the rest of the data (day and year) I think the solution from Ronak will take care of it.